# Background images - even small ones - not displaying on mobile

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, image

I've never encountered this one before - my background images are fine on the desktop but completely invisible on mobile. Not even a "bitmappy" version appears, though the space for them is held open, so to speak.

http://www.compassionglobally.org

I've read several similar questions here on StackOverflow but the issue always seems to be the file size (and iOS's enforced limits in that area). But even quite small images - there are four of them down the page - don't show up.

This is a WordPress site, but I feel like that's probably not relevant here... but I guess I should mention that.

Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the images not showing, right?

http://localhost/compassionglobally.org/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cg/library/images/site/baby.jpg

Well,

[image]

The link above is pointed to an image on the computer that is hosting the site (localhost). That file cannot be found on either your phone, or my laptop.

The fact that *"the space for them is held open"* is irrelevent, as you've set the div to be 250px high and 250px wide.

To solve the problem, you just need to remove the *"localhost/"* from the start of the links, like this:

http://compassionglobally.org/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cg/library/images/site/baby.jpg

Comment: I use a script to help automate the task of updating your image file paths: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: what exactly do you mean by your last comment? My addition was nothing more than an addition to your already correct answer. It was a noted way of automating the task, and yes, that script does indeed work. It works well, as I have used it on a very large number of sites (in this exact instance of pushing from a local dev environment to a remote server).

Comment: @Ryan Oh sorry there, I thought you were the OP complaining about something.

Comment: All good @James. I probably should have validated my first comment better when initially posting it.

Comment: @Ryan Judging by the OP's answer below, do you think my answer fixed his problem?

Comment: Absolutely, @James

Answer (score 0):

To quote Bill the Cat... ACK!!!

I'm still fairly new to the "best practice" site-building method of local development, then uploading to the server. Thought I'd worked out a good system but of course I neglected to check my CSS for local references!

Thank you, I'm sure I will solve this fairly obvious-in-retrospect problem quickly now.